# JQuery validation on SharePoint Edit/New Form before the OK button

Tags: jquery

I used SharePoint at work and our edit form have an appointment date and an end date.  I want the end date to copy whatever the appointment date is.

//Appointment Date

```
 $('input[title="Appointment Date"]').blur(function() {
  $('input[title="End"]').val($(this).val());
  });
```

This copies the date. (I tried to post a image so you can see but I am not allowed yet)

But they don't have title for hours and minutes.

I can use the long id which is

//Appointment Hour

```
$('select[name="ctl00$m$g_29cbb5be_bcd6_4949_875d_8fad4732db9b$ctl00$ctl05$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]').blur(function() {
$('select[name="ctl00$m$g_29cbb5be_bcd6_4949_875d_8fad4732db9b$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]').val($(this).val());
  });
```

//Appointment Min

```
$('select[name="ctl00$m$g_29cbb5be_bcd6_4949_875d_8fad4732db9b$ctl00$ctl05$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes"]').blur(function() {
$('select[name="ctl00$m$g_29cbb5be_bcd6_4949_875d_8fad4732db9b$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes"]').val($(this).val());
  });
```

but I am afraid the name id will change over time.

I tried doing

```
 $("label:contains('Appointment Date Hours')").blur(function(){
$("label:contains('End Hours')").next.($(this).next().val()).val();
});  <--- This doesn't work
```

Maybe its written in a wrong way but I can't figure it out. I tried doing `.next().val($(this).next().val());`but it didn't work

i got that label from

`var apptHour = $("label:contains('Appointment Date Hours')").next().val();` in our javascript valdiation

Also, I know the text is called "Appointment Date Hours" because I found it using the developer tools from IE.

Comment: You can't bind `blur` on a `label`

Comment: really? How about `.change()`

Comment: I was pointing to this --> `$("label:contains('Appointment Date Hours')").blur`

Comment: Yes, I understand but I would like to know if I can use `.change` or if you have a better suggestions?

Comment: In sharepoint, the event in javascript that is called when ytou click on save or ok is PreSaveAction(). Put your validation in that function and it will be executed when you clcik on the save button. If that method returns true, the save happens, if it returns false, the save aborts. Hope it helps!